# useReducer to retain object state and update a specific item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to update a specific item within an object is causing the application to crash.

The specific object looks as follows:

```
auth: {
    user: {
        id: string;
        emailVerified: boolean;
        onBoarded: boolean;
    }    
}
```

The reducer looks like this:

```
case 'USER_ONBOARDED':
  return { ...state, user: { ...state.user, onBoarded: true } };
```

and it's execution:

```
dispatch({ type: 'USER_ONBOARDED' });
```

What am I doing wrong, why can't I just update the onBoarded state and set it to true, and retain the rest of the data items against the user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is inside auth, so you need to update it by considering that in mind too

```
case 'USER_ONBOARDED':
     return { 
       ...state, 
       auth: {
          ...state.auth, 
          user: { 
             ...state.auth.user, 
             onBoarded: true 
          } 
       }
     };
```

Comment: You got it. Good!